# Is there any R BG/BB/NBD Models based on Customer transactions plus Purchase amount?

Tags: r

R BTYD and Forecast packages are great and I am able to forecast and predict ‘Customer frequency patterns’, parameter estimation etc. Interestingly these two packages are only care about ‘Customer frequency, not about ‘purchase amount’. But our problem is our customers are coming same frequency but they are not buying as much as they used to buy from us. 
Is there any R packages would consider both Frequency and purchase amount?

Appreciate for your kind advice.

Comment: What is the structure of your data/prediction problem?

Comment: Here is one R package that I am aware of https://code.google.com/p/clv-master-thesis/. I know that there are a few others on github by students of Pete.

Comment: Data structure:
Customer Number, Item ID, Item Count, Sales Date, Sales amount in $$$
We are trying to predict..
1. Customer purchase time and customer average $$$ amount in each purchase.

Comment: Thanks Ramnath, CLV master thesis is about BTYD package. I tried and I haven’t found prediction about ‘purchase amount $$$’. But BTYD package is wonderful in predicting future transactions but we are looking for ‘average purchase price’ along with future transaction as well (based on our past data).

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the BTYD package carefully. you can find the GG model for getting expected value of mean transaction amount of money. If the frequency and average amount of transaction follow gamma distribution then you will get a nice result.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow by the new R package CLVTools makes it straightforward to estimate both the number of expected future purchases and as well as their monetary value: https://cran.r-project.org/package=CLVTools

Have a look at the step-by-step walk-through based on data from an apparel retailer: https://www.clvtools.com/articles/CLVTools.html

As mentioned by [Boram Lim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3714137/boram-lim), estimating the monetary value relies on estimating a Gamma/Gamma model.